# Getdate() function is returning different result than DateTime.Now in dotnet

Tags: .net, sql-server

If I run these two functions I am getting different result. The `datetime.Now` in dotnet is showing the same result as it is showing in the system time while there is a difference of around 20 minutes if i use `getdate()`... what is the cause, and how to overcome this?

Comment: Are the server times the same?

Comment: I guess from the tags you mean the `GetDate()` function in SQL Server. Are the database and the .NET code on the same machine?

Comment: Yes, they are on same machine

Comment: @learner123: to be clear, do you mean the SQL Server engine is running on the same machine? Or just the client tools?

Comment: Are you sure the difference is 20 *minutes* and not 20 *milliseconds* ? Give examples of the output to see?

Comment: @Neil Fenwick: that is an excellent point. Sample output would be nice

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The 2 machines have different system times.

- `GETDATE` gets time from the server where SQL Server is installed (where it runs).
- `DateTime.Now` gets time from the App or Web server or your local PC.

Don't mix up "machine that sends `GETDATE()` command" and "machine that runs it".

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Windows Time Service to synchronize machine's clocks.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307897